# hide an object from another class

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to hide an object in my viewController, with code executed from a custom class, but the object is nil.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

- (void) hideLabel;
```

**FirstViewController.m**
I synthesize testLabel and I have a function to hide it. If I call the function from viewDidAppear it works, but I want to call it from my other class. When called from the other class, testLabel is nil

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "OtherClass.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize testLabel;

- (void) hideLabel {
    self.testLabel.hidden=YES;
    NSLog(@"nil %d",(testLabel==nil)); //here I get nil 1 when called from OtherClass
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    OtherClass *otherClass = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
    [otherClass hideThem];
    //[self hideLabel]; //this works, it gets hidden
}
```

**OtherClass.h**

```
@class FirstViewController;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OtherClass : NSObject {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *firstViewController;

-(void)hideThem;

@end
```

**OtherClass.m**
calls the hideLabel function in FirstViewController. In my original project, (this is an example obviously, but the original project is at work) I download some data here and I want to hide my loading label and indicator when download is done

```
#import "OtherClass.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation OtherClass
@synthesize firstViewController;

-(void)hideThem {
    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    //[firstViewController.testLabel setHidden:YES]; //it doesn't work either
    [firstViewController hideLabel];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UILabel` is nil because you just initialized your controller but didn't load it's view. Your controller`s IBoutlets are instantiated from the xib or storyboard automatically when you ask access to the bound view for the first time, so in order to access them you first have to load its view by some means.

**EDIT** (after OP comments):

Since your `FirstViewController` is already initialized and your `OtherClass` is instantiated by that controller, you could just hold a reference to it and not try to initialize a new one.
So try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    OtherClass *otherClass = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
    otherClass.firstViewController = self;
    [otherClass hideThem];
}
```

In your **OtherClass.m**:

```
-(void)hideThem {
    [self.firstViewController hideLabel];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but viewDidLoad is executed before. I tested it by putting NSLog(@"View Did Load") in viewDidLoad and I get it before I get "nil 1".
Should I reload the FirstViewController? How could I do that?

Comment: Try to change your `alloc init` to `alloc initWithNibName:bundle:`

Comment: Tried initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you trying to present your `FirstViewController` through your `OtherClass` or it's already loaded and you just want to call a method on it? Also, where do you instantiate your `OtherClass` ?

Comment: FirstViewController is already loaded. I call [otherClass hideThem]; in FirstViewController's viewDidAppear where I instantiate OtherClass as well. I call [firstViewController hideLabel]; from my otherClass

Comment: Ok now I get it, I am not sure why you're trying to do it like so but I will edit my answer to give you an insight.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! I spent all day yesterday trying to do that. It finally worked!

Comment: _Parakalw_ Also note that you should not `retain` your `firstViewController` property, just use `unsafe_unretained` (or `weak` if you're using ARC) instead :)

Comment: Eyxaristw again ;) Have a nice day!